# How to redirect to different index.php with two htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have installed 2 different scripts one in the root folder and the second one in the sub folder.

The two scripts are redirected to index.php located in their respective folders

When I access the subfolder pages I am sent to the 404 page of the parent folder except the subfolder homepage.

**htaccess folder:**

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

**htaccess subfolder:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>

        Options -MultiViews


    </IfModule>

  RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?website\.it)$ [NC]

RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...


    # Handle Front Controller...

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't post the code properly

Comment: "the 404 page of the parent folder" - By that I assume you mean the request is being routed through `/index.html` and that is generating the "404 page"?

Answer (score 0):

> When I access the subfolder pages I am sent to the 404 page of the parent folder except the subfolder homepage.

This will happen if the `.htaccess` file in the subfolder is not actually being processed. It's possible that `AllowOverride` (that essentially enables/disables `.htaccess` files) has only been configured for the root directory. This can only be configured in the server/vHost config.

When you access the "subfolder homepage" the `.htaccess` is not required at all (and the directives would not be processed) since mod_dir serves the `DirectoryIndex` document from that directory.

You could combine both `.htaccess` files into a single config file in the root directory.

For example:

```
Options -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

RewriteEngine on

# Remove www subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?website\.it)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Front-controller for subfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(subfolder)/. $1/index.php [L]

# Front-controller for root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

I've assumed you would want to remove the www subdomain regardless of which script you are accessing.

The `<IfModule>` wrappers are not required unless these directives are *optional* (which does not appear to be the case).